# making a leader-board that displays top 10 players?

Tags: java, android, listview, sqlite, leaderboard

i'm having a problem with a leader board that i created to display top 10 players with the highest scores but instead it desplayes the lowest first in reverse order, i've tried to change the select statment and the version of the database and that didn't work any one has any idea how to solve this?
here is the Leader-board activity:

```
package com.example.tabsnav;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import library.DBhelper;
import library.DBhelper.DatabaseHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LeaderBoard extends Activity {
ArrayList<Leaders> imageArry = new ArrayList<Leaders>();
ImageAdapter adapter;
EditText etcomment1;
//Button b1;
DBhelper db;
TextView etname1;
ListView dataList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leader_board);




}

    @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    adapter.clear();
}
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
db = new DBhelper(this);
db.open();


// Reading all comments from database

List<Leaders> contacts = db.getAllContactsFromAndroid();

for (Leaders cn : contacts) {
    String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
            + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

    // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Result: ", log);
    //add contacts data in arrayList
    imageArry.add(cn);

}
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.leader_list_adapter,
        imageArry);
dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

my get function in the database:

```
// Getting All Contacts From Android
public List<Leaders> getAllContactsFromAndroid() {
    List<Leaders> contactList = new ArrayList<Leaders>();
    // Select All Query
    Cursor cursor=null;
    cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM Game DESC ORDER by score LIMIT 10",
            null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Leaders contact = new Leaders();
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(G_FIRSTNAME)));
            contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(G_PHOTO)));
            contact.setComment(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(G_SCORE)));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Leader Class to set and get data:

```
package com.example.tabsnav;

public class Leaders {

// private variables
int _id;
String _name;
byte[] _image;
int _comment;

// Empty constructor
public Leaders() {

}
// constructor
    public Leaders(int keyId, String name, byte[] image,int comment) {
        this._id = keyId;
        this._name = name;
        this._image = image;
        this._comment=comment;

    }

// constructor
public Leaders(int keyId, String name, byte[] image) {
    this._id = keyId;
    this._name = name;
    this._image = image;

}

// constructor
public Leaders(String contactID, String name, byte[] image) {
    this._name = name;
    this._image = image;

}

// constructor
public Leaders(String name, byte[] image) {
    this._name = name;
    this._image = image;
}


// getting ID
public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int keyId) {
    this._id = keyId;
}

// getting name
public String getName() {
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name) {
    this._name = name;
}

// getting phone number
public byte[] getImage() {
    return this._image;
}

// setting phone number
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this._image = image;
}

// getting comment
public int getComment() {
    return this._comment;
}

// setting comment
public void setComment(int comment) {
    this._comment = comment;
}
}
```

here is a screen shot of the leader board:
[image: as you see it displays it in the wrong order]

Comment: Try `cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM Game ORDER by score DESC ", null);` Also, if the app still crashes, please post the error log so we can see what went wrong

Comment: Your error is saying that `fname` column doesn't exist in the table `questions`. Is that the correct column name? Is that the correct table name?

Comment: i made a mistake the table constant was Game_TABLE still gives a cursor error

Comment: It says you're trying to read `row 0, col -1`. You can't access negative indexed columns.

Comment: thanks already solved and yeah it was a mistake in columns parameter beside the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE}, null, null, null, null,KEY_SCORE+" DESC","LIMIT 10");

Comment: do i have to put all of my columns constants in the column parameter ?

Comment: No, but you can if you want. I think in your case it's the name and the score you want.

Comment: also it gives a run time exception unable to resume activity !!

Comment: You are actually doing to much inside onResume. I think its not the best place to do such long works. Add db.close() after 
List<Leaders> contacts = db.getAllContactsFromAndroid(); and give the update.

Comment: still the same exception! i'm really suffering with this its almost two weeks trying to fix it. thanks anyway

Comment: Edit your question with log outputs.

Comment: It says no such column fname. I think you put wrong table name, it should be Game right? Log shows you are querying on questions table. Also check your .db files column names and corresponding key values if you made it externally.

Comment: problem solved by using this :  mDb.query(GAME_TABLE, new String[] { G_PHOTO,
    G_FIRSTNAME, G_LASTNAME, G_USERNAME, G_EMAIL, G_UID, G_SCORE }, null, null, null, null,G_SCORE+" DESC"); thank you very much

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the log because it's off topic. People, if come across this in future wouldn't find log helpful.

Comment: Yeah i had that idea in mind too and already did :) thanks tho

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie FYI there's an overloaded method of query () which supports limit on its last parameter. i.e. query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)

Answer (score 1):

Your SQLite query is not correct. Try something like below:

```
cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Game ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10",
            null);
```

Comment: didn't work and the app crashes RunTime Exception Unable to resume activity